# How to install Nvidia 9400m driver on El Capitan?

Tags: macos, gpu, driver

I have a Mid 2009 MacBook Pro that updated itself to El Capitan.

There are no drivers for El Capitan at the Nvidia site, only for Snow Leopard that work for 9400m Nvidia.

Is there any way i can install this package in El Capitan without breaking my OS?

Comment: Are you experiencing any problems since the update to El Capitan (i.e. Do you actually need to update the driver)?